# Quickbooks integration in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, quickbooks

I am new to Quickbooks. I looked at the integrations that they support but could not narrow down to the best approach.

I am dealing with QuickBooks Desktop (Mac) and trying to integrate with a rails application.

I found a couple of options:

- QuickBooks Desktop REST API (Can this be used in rails and mac environment? Also there is an announcement on it's deprecation: https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/09/08/timeline-to-discontinue-the-quickbooks-desktop-rest-api)
- QuickBooks SDK (Can this be used in rails and mac environment. If yes, how?)
- QuickBooks Web Connector (There is a gem qbwc https://github.com/qbwc/qbwc but not sure on what after this and can this be used in rails and mac environment?)

Hence the question: What is the best way to integrate quickbooks in a rails application for retrieving customers data, creating/sending invoice for them etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am dealing with QuickBooks Desktop (Mac)

Then you're stuck.

QuickBooks for Mac *does not support any type of integration at all*.

- The QuickBooks desktop REST API is Windows-only (and no longer
  functional). It used a Windows COM bridge to talk to QuickBooks for
  Windows.
- The QuickBooks SDK uses the same COM bridge as above, for QuickBooks
  for Windows.
- The QuickBooks Web Connector is a SOAP wrapper around the QuickBooks
  SDK, and thus depends on the Windows COM components as above.

You should either move to QuickBooks Online, or QuickBooks for Windows (it runs great in VMWare Fusion on a Mac).

> What is the best way to integrate quickbooks in a rails application for retrieving customers data, creating/sending invoice for them etc.?

If you're using QuickBooks *for Mac*, there isn't a way.

QuickBooks desktop for Windows -- use the Web Connector.

QuickBooks Online -- use the v3 REST APIs.

Comment: Okay thanks so much for the detailed input. So if we move to QuickBooks Online, I should be able to use https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby right? I just want to know if there are any limitations with this gem in terms of the operations i listed above.

Comment: Correct, QuickBooks Online and that Ruby Gem is the way to go.